# Orientation in OpenGL MonoTouch game

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

Looking for the proper way to handle orientation in my MonoTouch game (although answers in Obj-C are fine).

We are looking to support LandscapeLeft and LandscapeRight orientations, but preserve the native OS orientation so the volume popup and notification center panel are not upside-down.

It is quite confusing, as there are several ways to accomplish what we need:

1. Info.plist settings
2. shouldrotate override in UIViewController
3. setting UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation
4. or just hook into the NSNotificationCenter and perform rotation with OpenGL, translating touch events

The best I've gotten to work is using #1 and #4, which also seems to be recommended by Apple for performance reasons.  I read some documentation saying that rotating a view (via option #2) with OpenGL content can hurt perf, see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html) under performance section. (We'd like our game to run pretty well on even older iPod Touches)

My issue is that when rotated LandscapeRight, everything draws properly in my game, but the volume and notification center are upside down in the OS.

Is there a better way to go about this?

I took a look at what some other games *appear* to do:

1. Angry Birds - rotate with OpenGL, however works appropriately in LandscapeRight
2. Jump Out - rotates with UIViewController
3. Tiny Wings - doesn't rotate at all

I'd like to get rotation exactly like Angry Birds working in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the supported orientations in the project Target settings, but I'm only rotating a view without OpenGL.

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Comment: I don't have a Mac in front of me to try it, but I feel like I tried this option and had issues with my game scaling weird.  I noticed pixellation throughout my scene as if everything were stretched (maybe the backbuffer was portrait while my game landscape).  Do you notice that issue in your game?

Comment: Your method worked pretty well after I set ContentMode to TopLeft on my UIView.  I also had to reverse some coordinates in my calls to GL.Ortho and Gl.Viewport.  I will have to wait and see if there really are any perf issues.

Comment: I did have a scaling issue one time - it was due to movement off screen and the device trying to rescale to keep it on screen. I was allowing settings screens to scale, but didn't switch it back to prevent it in the game screen.